# Converting to a Java Facebook application, from a Google App Engine application written in Java

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-apps

I have created a web application hosted on [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) (Java). Now my client wants a Facebook application of it. All I need to ask is: Is it possible?

The problem is that all I see is the Python version of Google App Engine for Facebook development, so is it possible to **build a Facebook application (Java) with my application hosted on Google App Engine (Java platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Facebook application that is IFrame based](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/). This way Facebook will host your application inside an IFrame.

Comment: 0o0o0o now i get it thanks... and as i have searched i will be needing  Facebook SDK for checking the Facebook login and all so my concern is will Google App Engine supports Facebook SDK or not?

Comment: @user958414 There are plenty of facebook apps that use GAE as a backend. I'm pretty sure that the java sdk works on GAE, you can also use the Javascript SDK.